# How can I send key event to inactive window in python

Tags: python, winapi, macros

I am trying to make macro with python

How can I send key event to inactive

Window?

Comment: You can't. Simple as that. If you want to automate an application, use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: Actually win32api.SendMessage worked

Comment: This is another case of ignoring the difference between *"correct code"* and *"code, that has not yet failed"*. Your code is in the latter category. [Here's why](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).